# Way to Setup More than single "Last Import"

Tags: photos.app, photos

Is there a way to have more than just a single "Last Import," like a second from last-type import. Its automatic event creation won't work as some imports (especially from our iPhones) span a larger amounts of time than the dSLR or point and shoots.

Any ideas on other ways to get several "imports?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I had a "duh" moment. As long as after each subsequent import, I select all within "Last Import" I can make a new album with that import's photos to organize at a later date.